# Pairing bluetooth devices with Passkey/Password in python - RFCOMM (Linux)

Tags: python, linux, bluetooth, pybluez

I am working on a Python script to search for bluetooth devices and connect them using *RFCOMM*. This devices has Passkey/Password. I am using PyBlueZ and, as far as I know, this library cannot handle Passkey/Password connections ([Python PyBluez connecting to passkey protected device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17089786/python-pybluez-connecting-to-passkey-protected-device)).

I am able to discover the devices and retrieve their names and addresses:

```
nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices(duration=4,lookup_names=True,
                                                      flush_cache=True, lookup_class=False)
```

But if tried to connect to a specific device using:

```
s = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM) 
s.connect((addr,port))
```

I get an error `'Device or resource busy (16)'`.

I tried some bash commands using the *hcitool* and *bluetooth-agent*, but I need to do the connection programmatically. I was able to connect to my device using the steps described here: [How to pair a bluetooth device from command line on Linux](http://www.heatxsink.com/entry/how-to-pair-a-bluetooth-device-from-command-line-on-linux).

I want to ask if someone has connected to a bluetooth device with Passkey/Password using Python. I am thinking about to use the bash commands in Python using `subprocess.call()`, but I am not sure if it is a good idea.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Finally I am able to connect to a device using PyBlueZ. I hope this answer will help others in the future. I tried the following:

First, import the modules and discover the devices.

```
import bluetooth, subprocess
nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices(duration=4,lookup_names=True,
                                                      flush_cache=True, lookup_class=False)
```

When you discover the device you want to connect, you need to know port, the address and passkey. With that information do the next:

```
name = name      # Device name
addr = addr      # Device Address
port = 1         # RFCOMM port
passkey = "1111" # passkey of the device you want to connect

# kill any "bluetooth-agent" process that is already running
subprocess.call("kill -9 `pidof bluetooth-agent`",shell=True)

# Start a new "bluetooth-agent" process where XXXX is the passkey
status = subprocess.call("bluetooth-agent " + passkey + " &",shell=True)

# Now, connect in the same way as always with PyBlueZ
try:
    s = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
    s.connect((addr,port))
except bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError as err:
    # Error handler
    pass
```

Now, you are connected!! You can use your socket for the task you need:

```
s.recv(1024) # Buffer size
s.send("Hello World!")
```

Official PyBlueZ documentation is available [here](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/karulis/pybluez/blob/master/docs/index.html)

Comment: Hi Yahya. Yes, it is a command. `bluetooth-agent` is a tool to manage the pairing code. You can read more about it:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/763939/bluetoothctl-what-is-a-bluetooth-agent
https://wiki.debian.org/BluetoothUser#Pairing_using_CLI

Comment: Alright, thanks, so it's basically: `your bluetooth agent` for example `bluetoothctl`

Comment: Yes. You can use `bluetoothctl` if you do not have `bluetooth-agent`

Comment: So is there a `bluetooth-agent` package that I can install or it is just a name the refer to the category which includes as I mentioned for example `bluetoothctl`?

Comment: According to http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/bluetooth-agent.1.html, if you have `bluez` installed is possible you already have `bluetooth-agent`. In Debian (https://wiki.debian.org/BluetoothUser#Pairing_using_CLI) they said "Bluetooth-agent is part of package bluez. So, if you use Debian testing or unstable, it should already be installed."

Comment: Any by the way for future readers, not all debians dists have `bluetooth-agent` , it's clearly mentioned that: "If `bluetooth-agent` is not available, try `bluetoothctl`"

Comment: is there something similar to `bluetoothctl` or `bluetooth-agent` to use in windows 10

Comment: Hi. I am not sure if there is something similar for Windows 10. Maybe you can check this link http://bluetoothinstaller.com/bluetooth-command-line-tools/

Comment: Hi ! In my case, the remote device will prompt its security passcode only when it gets a connexion request. How to manage this with this code ? 

Thanks !

Comment: Hi Vincent, the prompt is on a display? If this is the case, I understand that the user needs to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to connect two phones via Bluetooth , the script should be running on a Linux host. Any suggestions of using pybluez or any other APIs?

I have seen some examples where a Linux host is used as Client and is connect a phone (which is a server), but here I'm want to use Linux host as just a device to run the script  and make two phones connect via Bluetooth.