# How do I connect two computers with Bluetooth and send and receive data between them using Python?

Tags: python, bluetooth

I just wanted to know how can I connect two computer with Bluetooth and send and receive data between them!

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37465157/pairing-bluetooth-devices-with-passkey-password-in-python-rfcomm-linux) answer might be helpful.