# Writing multiple commands to a subprocess

Tags: python, bluetooth, subprocess

I am trying to script a Bluetooth connection to a device that requires a PIN to be paired from a Linux machine. None of [`pygatt`](https://github.com/peplin/pygatt) or [`pybluez`](https://github.com/pybluez/pybluez) can handle the PIN input. I figured out that subprocesses would be the right solution! The problem is, however, that pairing bluetooth devices requires sequential commands and analyzing the output so I can't just run commands from Python.

What I was able to do until now:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(['bluetoothctl'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1)
p.stdin.write(b'agent') # First command in my procedurebluetoothctl
p.stdin.close()
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
    print line,
p.stdout.close()
p.wait()
```

This works just fine! It prompts me `agent registered`, which is what I would get if I ran `bluetoothctl` then "agent on" in a terminal.

However, I would like to go on and keep writing to this process, for example "scan on" to start scanning for devices or "devices" to list available devices. As far as I can understand, this is not possible as my code is written. Once the command is sent, the bridge is closed and if I try to do:

```
 p.stdin.write(b'devices')
```

I'll get an error `writing to closed file`.

My question: What is the correct way to keep sending and reading with this subprocess? Or a suitable alternative? I have read about `subprocess.communicate()` but wasn't able to get any improvement, it closes anyway.

I also have read about [`pexpect`](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) but I don't see how to use it to solve my problem.

Comment: hope the following URL helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37465157/pairing-bluetooth-devices-with-passkey-password-in-python-rfcomm-linux

Comment: Thanks @MountMani ! It would have helped in a classic configuration, except that this is for Bluetooth previous generations. On bluetooth4 devices, you may not know the pass key in advance. It is generated by some devices and asked as a response :( I have had an idea in the night which I’m going to try ASAP and I’ll come post it if it works. Thanks again !